# Reason for this error during OPENCV haar training?

Tags: .net, opencv

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (rect.width >= 0 && rect.height >= 0 && rect.x <
image->width && rect.y < image->height && rect.x + rect.width >= (int)(rect.widt
h > 0) && rect.y + rect.height >= (int)(rect.height > 0)) in unknown function, f
ile c:\Users\vp\work\ocv\opencv\modules\core\src\array.cpp, line 3006
```

I get this error when I do sampling of the positive images. I have a total of 1200 positive samples. 
In many places it mentioned that the dimensions being passed to CvSetImageROI() are greater than the maximum dimension allowed.
I am using a web cam that produces images with dimensions of 640x480.

Code for Sampling:
`opencv_createsamples.exe -info lent.txt -vec vec\Samples.vec -w 24 -h 24`
Other thing that I did was changing the dimensions of the samples to 30x32/30x30/32x32 and many,but the error persists.

What do I do now ?
NB: This could be a possible duplicate question, but the previous ones did not help me.

Please help!

Comment: Can you try to provide a Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example (http://sscce.org/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was some error in saving the ROI of the images. The first image could not satisfy the dimensions and hence it raised the error!

I have solved that error!